# Using .wrapAll width of child is ignored

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

A [WordPress site](http://www.gliljevall.se) where the client have different pages where he is adding images one after another. To be able to show this as he like there's some jQuery wrapping the images with a `div` and class of `.postImg`:

The script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var set = jQuery('#content > img');  
    for(var i = 0, len = set.length; i < len; i += 1){
        set.slice(i, i+1).wrapAll('<div class="postImg" />');
    };
});
```

When loading the site first it seems just fine, but if you reload or click the menu items the added divs seem to not recognizing the child width and ignores it. Basically the div's are "loosing" their widths and stacked side by side.

I've been struggling with understanding what is happening and why, as well as trying different solutions just to see if there's any result. But nothing. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Please use this fiddle to better assist in isolating/solving the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2cLJZ/

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Make a grid etc, and what you think that your javascript is doing, would help too. I'm betting your javascript is being called to early or something... is it in the head? or at the end of the body? Call your scripts at the end, so that it has the DOM figured out before it starts trying to add classes etc maybe ?

Comment: Very kind of @cantera to put up a fiddle. I think the main problem of your question is that people need more code to reproduce the problem, but [only the minimum necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late answer, totally forgot about my question here.
[Pic here of what happened](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5866713/IMG_9335.jpg)
But I managed to find some kind of interference with a wordpress plugin that the client installed without (his own) and my knowledge.
Removing the plugin fixed the problem.
And to better answer what I was trying to do:
The posts in WP is just simple images one after another, and the design is that it's an horizontal scroll. To be able to get the img to not break line I needed to wrap each img in divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the plug-ins on the site and found one that interfered with the jQuery resulting in the misbehavior.
Removing this plug-in fixed the problem.